# How to break a string apart by a character the occurs multiple times in SQL

Tags: sql, ssms

I am looking to break a column into two columns by a character. Some of the rows have the character occuring multiple times and I need to key on the last occuring one.

Example:
400000007_MOD-HUD_1-1.jpg

I want to break into two columns

Column 1: 400000007_MOD-HUD_1

Column 2: -1.jpg

The data looks like this,

200000297_R-1_1-1.jpg

400000007_MOD-HUD_1-1.jpg

500000334_R-1_1-1.jpg

500000334_R-2_MOD_HUD_1-1.jpg

500000342_MOD-HUD_1-1.jpg

1200000177_MOD-HUD_1-1.jpg

1300000433_C-1-EQSHED_1-1.jpg

1300000433_C-3-UB_1-1.jpg

2100000375_C_1-5_Barn_1-1.jpg

The character I want to split them by is "-". This character occurs multiple times in some of these file names and I want to key on the last occuring one.

Comment: Please tag your particular database platform.

Comment: Any specific character in mind?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some more sample data and expected result! [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *possible* solution you can try. Possible as I'm *guessing* you want to break on the last `-` character. Assuming *ssms* tag implies SQL Server, try the following:

```
select Left(col,Len(col)-p) Col1, Right(col,p) Col2
from t
cross apply (values(CharIndex('-',Reverse(col))))x(p)
```

[Demo DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b60f51b0907b8f16b05567fb188b4b5b)

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for!